# Image Searching Library

Tags: image, search

I want to create .NET application that accepts an image and scans all images in a folder and find those that look similar it.

Any suggestion where I should start? Are there any free/open source libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/). The [ExhaustiveTemplateMatching](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/) method does exactly that. There's an example in the documentation:

```
// create template matching algorithm's instance
// use zero similarity to make sure algorithm will provide anything
ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching( 0 );
// compare two images
TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage( image1, image2 );
// check similarity level
if ( matchings[0].Similarity > 0.95f )
{
    // do something with quite similar images
}
```

Comment: This only works for images of the same size. If there a way to make it work even for images of different sizes?